# setup donation system in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions, paypal

Ok so there is this feature that I would like to implement on my site. Users can choose to donate money to a specific nonprofit (let's say Wikipedia). So they click donate and they choose the amount on the website, get redirected to PayPal website, complete the transaction, and then get redirected to my website AFTER I get some Instant Notification, with which I track that donation in my website database with the users info.

I looked up some Railscasts video about PayPal, but they were all mostly about e-commerce. How can I set up the system to wire the money directly to Wikipedia's PayPal account and how can I get the notification back? I really could appreciate it if someone could assist me with this.

P.S I am running the localhost server for now, will that be a problem?

Comment: What will you do for nonprofits that don't have PayPal accounts?

Comment: For now we are just targeting one nonprofit with a PayPal account. It's in very early stages, so we gotta start small...

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called a "third party transaction" since the first two parties to the transaction are the donor and the recipient org (eg Wikipedia).

From my quick search of PayPal, I don't think it is supported. Even if it is supported, you'd need approval from each of the recipients to set it up. Eg see this Paypal [3rd party shopping cart article](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ButtonMgrAPIIntro#id0941D10J05Z)

[Amazon Flexible Payments Service](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/) does support third party payments. Again, you'd need the co-operation of the recipients.

You could have the donors pay money to you which you would then turn around and donate to the non-profits. But to do so, either your donors would lose the tax deductions or you'd need to become a non-profit yourself. In addition, there would be two sets of transaction fees, yours and the recipients.

Comment: Im looking this up right now. I will let you know how it goes. Thanks!